# Duda sobre definicion de clases

Tags: java, clase

Buenas. Soy nuevo en JAVA. Mi duda es acerca de la definición de un metodo cuyo valor de retorno es del mismo tipo de la clase que se esta definiendo. Realmente no entiendo como funciona este mecanismo.

Dejo un extracto de una clase para mostrar mi duda. Además no comprendo como se puede definir un objeto `Fraccion c=new Fraccion();` dentro de la definición de la clase `Fraccion`.

Dentro de los metodos se define `Fraccion c=new Fraccion();` que es del mismo tipo de la clase que se está definiendo y los métodos sumar y restar que devuelven un dato de tipo Fraccion.

```
public class Fraccion {

       private int num;
       private int den;

       public Fraccion() {

        num=0;
        den=1;
       }

       public Fraccion(int x, int y) {

         num=x;
         den=y;
       }

       public static Fraccion sumar(Fraccion a, Fraccion b){

         Fraccion c=new Fraccion();
         c.num=a.num*b.den+b.num*a.den;
         c.den=a.den*b.den;
         return c;
       }

      public static Fraccion restar(Fraccion a, Fraccion b){

        Fraccion c=new Fraccion();
        c.num=a.num*b.den-b.num*a.den;
        c.den=a.den*b.den;
        return c;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Si eres nuevo en Java, creo que la explicación más útil que se te puede dar es simplemente... que se puede. Es legal hacer tal cosa, usar la propia clase que se está definiendo en métodos (o atributos) propios. Esto no es particular de Java sino de muchos lenguajes (incluso, hasta cierto punto, [en C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/506382/277304)).

Es entendible que esto te resulte algo paradójico (¿cómo puedo usar algo que todavía no he terminado de definir...?), pero no lo es tanto cuando piensas que en Java toda referencia de un objeto de una clase es.. una referencia, que es algo así como un número identificador (una especia de handle o puntero).

Por ejemplo, en las "menciones internas" a `Fraccion` aquí

```
public class Fraccion { ....
   public static Fraccion sumar(Fraccion a, Fraccion b){
      Fraccion c=new Fraccion();
      ...
   }
}
```

el compilador no tiene ninguna dificultad en entender e implementar lo anterior, incluso si "a esa altura todavía" (es un decir) no conoce totalmente la estructura de la clase `Fraccion`. Ver más en detalle cómo no hay ningún problema de el huevo y la gallina aquí, significaría meterse en detalles de implementación que, aunque interesantes, pueden estar fuera de lugar en un nivel principiante. Todos quienes aprendimos Java empezando aprendiendo que simplemente "se puede".

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Clara y concisa. Me gustarìa ahondar un poco en el tema en el futuro, si puedes darme alguna referencai bibliográfica o de algún sitio web que explique este tema te agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada la clase **Fraccion** fue creada para tener un tipo de dato que contenga un numerador y un denominador con los cuales se representa la fracción. 
La clase **Fracción** también ofrece métodos que son suma y resta de fracciones es por eso que el resultado de la operación debe ser devuelto cómo un tipo de dato Fraccion ya que este permite guardar un numerador y un denominador. 
En java una clase puede tener datos que sean del mismo tipo que la clase si así lo requiere.